# ARRAYFORMULA with a range that changes from cell to cell

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a list of items in column A. In column B I want to use an *ARRAYFORMULA* function that will bring the serial number of each item to appear - 1 next to the first item, 2 next to the second etc.

This formula works fine but breaks when there are blank rows:

*=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),ROW(A2:A)-1,""))*

This formula works nice but I need to drag it which I don't want to do. This is why I want it as an *ARRAYFORMULA* (note that I fix the range to always start from A$1 so only the range changes in size as I drag it further down).

*=IF(LEN(A2),COUNTA(A$1:A2),"")*

What I need is basically something that will work like the 2nd formula but with an *ARRAYFORMULA*.

Here's a spreadsheet to make it clearer (col A is the list, col C is function 1 and col D is function 2):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17qVGwvFJVrxdwkgmVQatH3Urpjl0_xB8EGqUsPVIwl8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F2 I entered

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), countifs(A2:A, "<>", row(A2:A), "<="&row(A2:A)),))
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it's working. Can you please explain the formula?

Comment: Hi, just pinging you again. Can you please explain the way this works? Thanks!